# How to use JSF version specified in POM (and not app server one)?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish

My application server is Glassfish 3.1.1, using Mojarra 2.0.3 FCS (as far as I know). I want my application to use JSF 2.1.2. I've already found the correct artifact to use in my maven build.

Now, how can I make sure the JSF classes are loaded from this artifact, instead of following "classical" delegation to Glassfish libvrary classloader (which will load JSF 2.0.3 and generate ClassNotFoundException for my omnifaces/richfaces additional components) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, how to override a specific Java EE artifact from an archive is application server specific. In case of GlassFish, if I'm not mistaken you can use the following in WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
    <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

What also works is replacing the jar in *[glassfish home]/glassfish/modules*. This is exactly what the JSF build script does as well, so it should be guaranteed to work.

Do note that if you go from something as low as 2.0.3 to a current version, you'll see that there has been a change from 2 jars to 1 jar. So in that case in *[glassfish home]/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/default-web.xml* and *[glassfish home]/glassfish/lib/templates/default-web.xml* remove the entries jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar and replace them by a single javax.faces.jar.

Perhaps an even easier alternative is to [download](http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html) the latest version of GlassFish (3.1.2.2).

Comment: The change from 2 JARs to 1 JAR was started in Mojarra 2.1.6. The OP is trying to use Mojarra 2.1.2 which is still 2 JARs (and which is 1.5 years old already, so I wonder the reason to go for such an old version).

Comment: Indeed, good catch. The OP is indeed puzzling. GlassFish 3.1.1 and then a desire to specifically go to Mojarra 2.1.2. Hmmmm....

Comment: @BalusC in fact, i'm not the official developer for that part of application, and as a consequence I'm also puzzled by such a requirement (which I will investigate later). To complement Arjan answer, [this blog article](http://blog.eisele.net/2012/07/upgrading-mojarra-in-glassfish.html) gives some good explanations of what the consequences of such a modification can be.